# Read csv in real time with python

Tags: python, csv, real-time-updates

I have a csv file that is writing some information on real-time with cicflowmeter. Is there a way to catch every new row in the time that it is writed with a python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved without any python code. Just run something like `tail -n0 -f logfile.csv | python3 program.py` and have your program read from stdin like this:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # do something
```